# Can I create a nested loop inside my function to return to the beginning of my code using (continue)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, nested-loops

I want my terminateProgram to loop back to the beginning but is throwing an error saying its not in the loop.

```
#this is the beginning of my code

while True: #I want it to loop back here

    import os 

    def terminateProgram(): #this is the function in question

        terminate = input('Would you like to end the program\nYes\nNo\n')

        if terminate == 'no':

            print('\nReturning\n')
            continue# these two lines 'continue and break' say they are not in the loop?
            break


        if terminate == 'yes':

            print('Terminating Program')
                    
            exit()
```

Comment: For the `terminate == 'no'` case just return from the function? If the code calling the function does nothing else, the loop will just continue anyway.

Comment: The `continue` keyword is causing the _not in the loop_ error because you have used it in a function, and the function cannot "know" that you are then putting it in a loop. Moreover, `break` will never be executed in any case, as `continue` makes the following iteration begin. Probably, you should better described the problem you are trying to solve with this implementation to get more valuable advice.

Comment: Doing the `import` inside the loop is harmless as such, but pretty completely crazy.